# Visual Studio 2019 editor tab order changed, not alphabetically?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

In Visual Studio 2017 and 2015 etc., when opening multiple files, the tabs are ordered in alphabetically. This is handy when I have my.component.html and my.component.ts opened, so tabs of the ts file and the html file of the same component could be together. In VS 2019, the earlier opened on the right and the newly opened on the left.

Is there any option to change?

Not sure if I had missed something in Tools/Options.

Comment: Were you using an extension like [Custom Document Well](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.CustomDocumentWell) (or Productivity Tools) in the earlier versions?  These added this functionality, but is missing ([so far](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/477172/tab-sorting-in-document-well.html)) in VS 2019.

Comment: I have Productivity Tools for vs 2019 installed.

Comment: What did you have in earlier versions? ([Productivity Power Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.ProductivityPowerPack2017) for 2019 does not incldule the component that adds tab sorting.)